# Resign Keyboard from UIWebView when i'm in google maps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, xcode4

I'm opening an UIWebView from my iPad Application as a PresentModalViewController and opening google maps "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=London" , everything is working fine but the only problem is when i search places source and destination and click on arrow button the **keyboard is not resigning**, but it is working fine when i open it in safari.
How to resign my keyboard when i click arrow button inside UIWebview?
Any help is thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resign responder in the DidEndEditing of the textField delegate?

Comment: @cocoakamali: Can you please read the question again? In the question i have clearly specified that i am opening a google maps page. So from where on earth can i get control of that textfield..
BTW thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing delegate `UIWebViewDelegate` and catching the event when the page is being reloaded. I am not sure which arrow button you mean, but I believe that when you click that button the UIWebView loads the previous web page. At that point `webViewDidStartLoad` should be called, in which you can try to call resignFirstResponder on UIWebView.